# How to pass a 2D dynamically allocated array to a function?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a 2 dimensional array dynamically allocated in my C code, in my function main. I need to pass this 2D array to a function. Since the columns and rows of the array are run time variables, I know that one way to pass it is :

-Pass the rows and column variables and the pointer to that [0][0] element of the array

```
myfunc(&arr[0][0],rows,cols)
```

then in the called function, access it as a 'flattened out' 1D array like:

```
ptr[i*cols+j]
```

But I don't want to do it that way, because that would mean a lot of change in code, since earlier, the 2D array passed to this function was statically allocated with its dimensions known at compile time.

So, how can I pass a 2D array to a function and still be able to use it as a 2D array with 2 indexes like the following?

```
arr[i][j].
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the code below. After passing the 2d array base location as a double pointer to `myfunc()`, you can then access any particular element in the array by index, with `s[i][j]`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void myfunc(int ** s, int row, int col) 
{
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<col; j++)
            printf("%d ", s[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int row=10, col=10;
    int ** c = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*row);
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
        *(c+i) = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*col);
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<col; j++)
            c[i][j]=i*j;
    myfunc(c,row,col);
    for (i=0; i<row; i++) {
        free(c[i]);
    }
    free(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is it - albeit the code has slight errors in the mem. alloc part.. but got the gist.

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports C99 variable-length-arrays (eg. GCC) then you can declare a function like so:

```
int foo(int cols, int rows, int a[][cols])
{
    /* ... */
}
```

You would also use a pointer to a VLA type in the calling code:

```
int (*a)[cols] = calloc(rows, sizeof *a);
/* ... */
foo(cols, rows, a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You really can't do this without changing a lot of code. I suggest to wrap this in a structure which contains the limits and then use regexp search'n'replace to fix the accesses.

Maybe use a macro like `AA(arr,i,j)` (as in Array Access) where `arr` is the structure.

Comment: So basically u are saying - no programatic way to get it done, but 'search and replace'. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, all you can pass to a function is a pointer to the first element of an array. When you pass an actual array to a function, it is said that "the array decays into a pointer" so no information about the size(s) of the pointed array remains.

> A reference to an object of type array-of-T which appears in an expression decays (with three exceptions) into a pointer to its first element; the type of the resultant pointer is pointer-to-T.

I believe you will be able to find more information about this on the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Numerical recipes in C](http://www.nrbook.com/a/bookcpdf.php) (a book dealing mostly in matrices) suggests a way to do this cleanly and still deal with 2D matrices. Check out the section 1.2 "Matrices and 2D arrays" and the method [convert_matrix()](http://leopard.physics.ucdavis.edu/rts/p104b/nrutil.chttp://leopard.physics.ucdavis.edu/rts/p104b/nrutil.c).

Essentially what you need is to allocate a set of pointers to point to your row vectors. And pass this to your function along with the number of rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

A 2-d array in C is just an array of arrays. Here ya go:

```
void with_matrix(int **matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    int some_value = matrix[2][4];
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int **matrix;
    ... create matrix ...
    with_matrix(matrix, rows, cols);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int cols = 4;
    int rows = 3;
    char** charArray = new char*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        charArray[i] = new char[cols];
    }

    // Fill the array
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            charArray[i][j] = 'a';
        }
    }

    // Output the array
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            cout << charArray[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Please add more information about what you're trying to do